# Regular expression to get specific part of request parameter from Log entry?

Tags: java, regex

I have request parameter in the following format

```
"POST /upload/sendData.htm HTTP/1.1"
```

And I want to extract resource name from that which in this case is `upload/sendData.htm`

Any pointers on how to do this as in some cases the request comes like

```
"POST //upload/sendData.htm HTTP/1.1"
```

or

```
"POST ///upload/sendData.htm HTTP/1.1"
```

I am using Java

Comment: Its not always POST request..... it can be GET, PUT as well

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess, but is this what you're looking for?

```
POST \/+(\w+\/\w+.\w+)
```

http://rubular.com/r/IUlIH9LDzS

---

or maybe this

```
POST \/+(.+)\s
```

http://rubular.com/r/sdw51Ek1Wi

Comment: @bril in that case, you can certainly modify your regex to account for both of those, or you can just account for an abstract command, such as `^[A-Z]+ \/+(.+)\s`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
"^POST /+(.+) HTTP/1\.1$"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"/POST[ ]+\/+([^\/].+[^ ])[ ]+HTTP/"
```